# Issues with alerts and required check out for editing

Tags: document-library, alert

We are having an issue with alerts related to forced check-out in a document library.

We would like an alert to be sent whenever a document is uploaded to a particular document library.

Using the following settings:

Change Type:

- New items are added

Send Alerts for These Changes:

- Anything changes

The behavior we see is that if the Versioning settings -> "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" is enabled these alerts are not sent, if it is disabled they are.

This is in SharePoint 2007.

Comment: Did you check your ULS logs for any possible errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue by design in SharePoint.

When "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" is set to Yes, alerts set to only send on New Items are not sent. They are only sent for Changed Items with alert set when documents are changed. When set to No, alerts are always sent on New Items.

In SharePoint, if multiple changes are made to a document before the alert mail is generated, SharePoint alert will only send the latest change that was made. This is to prevent spamming with too many alerts or too many changes in a digest when people hit “save” again and again.

Once you choose “yes” for “require documents to be checked out before they can be edited” and then upload a new document, you will only get the “change” alert about “checked out” information as this change happens after the item is created. This is a by-design behavior.

Answer referred from [this post.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/948a168d-22f3-4a09-92d7-2e6558b0f0fb/)

Comment: This seems to represent a real gap in the design of this feature for the product. We are eligible for premier support and so I will open a ticket for final confirmation and give you the check if they confirm your finding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the document in after they have been checked out and modified.